# In Core Data, how do I access a specific attribute of every managed object (instance) of a given entity?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, attributes, fetch

This is the Core Data object model I am working with (I am a new user, so I can't post pictures directly):

http://i965.photobucket.com/albums/ae134/spindler77/Screenshot2010-07-26at112231AM.png

All I am trying to do right now is to populate a UITableView with the "className" of every myClass instance the user has created and saved.

My code for generating the myClass instances is fully functioning, but what I can't figure out is how to extract the "className" attribute (to put in my tableview cells) once I have fetched the myClass objects. I have read and re-read the Apple docs (though I'm sure the "answer" is there somewhere, I'm just having a hard time deciphering it).

I have scoured Core Data tutorials as well. The most helpful one that I found has only gotten me to a point where my managed objects are stored in an array, but I can't figure out how to access the attributes of those objects.

**My question: How do I access a specific attribute of every managed object (instance) of a given entity?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

-Michael

Comment: You're making the mistake of thinking of Core Data in terms of tables. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. As explained below, in Core Data, you fetch the objects you want and then ask them individually for the value of one or more attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've fetched all your objects into an NSArray, you can then just iterate through the array, for example using fast enumeration:

```
for (myClass *cl in array) {
    NSLog(@"Name = %@", cl.className);
}
```

Comment: That sounds right, but with that code I'm getting a warning that says, "Passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type" and the program quits with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at that line.

Comment: Oops, I left out the '@' in front of the string constant. NSLog expects an NSString format string, so it needs to be `@"Name = %@"` instead of `"Name = %@"` (without the '@', you get a C string, not an NSString). I'll correct the example.

Comment: Ah, I should have spotted that :P 

Alright, I'm almost there. Now I'm just not sure how to implement that in my cellForRowAtIndexPath. I want to access my array once for each indexPath. Currently, I have two classes stored, so I want to access it at array[0] and array[1] and extract the className from each. The "myClass *cl in array" format doesn't seem to work in that case. I tried "for (myClass *cl in array[indexPath]), but no luck.

Comment: If you just want a single element from the array, you do something like `[array objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: Thanks David, your input is very helpful. However, I may be asking the wrong question. I think I should be using an NSFetchedResultsController instead of fetching into an array. I will post a separate question about that, but as far as this question is concerned, you answered it. The iteration you provided works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I definitely recommend an NSFetchedResultsController for the case of displaying all your instances in a UITableView